# Keepass optional keyfile or password

Tags: keepass

I am using Keepass 2 for storing my passwords. The database is stored in the cloud. I would like to be able to open this in windows with a key file (or my windows user account) so i don't have to enter my password each time, but still be able to use a password only to open it at another location.

So far keepass only shows me the option to set both, but then i also have to login with both. How can i set it so that i have the choice between using a password or keyfile, and both will be able to unlock it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you want isn't possible with a single file. If you do enable multiple options you have to satisfy each option in order to open the file.

You could use independent files or look into saving one of the portions. Using your Windows Account could be a bad idea because as far as I know it's tied to the SID and private key that might be machine dependent (definitely if you use a local account it would be hard to restore).